# Re-using allocated memory in JS / browser?

Tags: javascript

I understand that memory allocation and release is controlled by the browser; but can allocated memory ever be programmatically re-used in JavaScript?

For example, suppose a function (getData) property (data) is used to store the results of an indexedDB `getAll` request, as ( I realize you'd never write code like this)

`getData.data = objectStore.getAll( keyRange ).result;`

Can subsequent invocations of `getData` re-use the memory already allocated from the previous invocation or will the browser always allocate a new area of memory to hold the result and just point `getData.data` to it, and later release the memory that held the previous results?

Thank you.

A reason for asking is from observing how memory is used in my application. This getData-type function may be invoked several hundred times in a user session and, as it is now, the RAM consumed continues to increase until a certain point is reached and then it is released. That is how the GC is supposed to work, I realize, but if the already allocated memory could be re-used, the applciation would never need to consume that much RAM at any given point.

I don't think there is a way to accomplish what I was considering because indexedDB will always allocate memory when it retrieves the objects from the object store. The `getAll` request will return a request object, the result of which will be an array of objects and, even if it were possible to write that result to an already exisiting array or object, nothing would be gained. All my code really only references or points to the result of the request; and the temporary increasing use of RAM usage will always continue until the GC runs, because the database request cannot be directly written to a specific area of memory from its 'creation' so to speak. The request object, including the result, will exist somewhere in RAM before object pooling or any other approach could be attempted.

The testing I mentioned in the comments was unrealistic, being comprised of 500 invocations of `getData` separated by only 500ms per invocation and the data retrieved in each invocation was far larger than would ever exist in the application under expected use. So, RAM usage had time to increase significantly before the GC ran. The RAM usage rose and fell several times as the 500 invocations processed in turn, each episode, I assume, being a run of the GC. I like the flat RAM usage graph in the object pooling article [here](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/static-mem-pools/) which minimizes GC runs; but it doesn't appear achievable when using indexedDB.

Comment: The real question is, what do you need manual re-using memory for? It sounds like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). JavaScript provides some objects for low-level memory management, but I'm pretty sure you don't need them

Comment: Thanks. What are those objects for low-level memory management to which you referred?

Comment: I reply to your edit. The browser is usually aware of what it is doing, and if it doesn't immediately free its memory there's a reason. Browsers like Chrome prefer postponing the garbage collection in the idle times, in order to speed up the current execution. This is also why Chrome appears to be so memory greedy. Usually you don't want to modify this behaviour

Comment: The objects that I'm talking about are, for example, [ArrayBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer) or [Uint32Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint32Array).

Comment: Furthermore, you may need a profiler to actually confirm that the indexedDB is the problem. Maybe you have a memory leak elsewhere and you didn't notice. Maybe you're keeping a reference to the previous objects

Comment: I think you're missing the point if you say that too much memory consumption before GC is bad. If you re-use the memory, it would be dirty, which is a constant problem in C. You don't *just* get the memory allocation, you also get whatever was inside at the time. Make your read slightly incorrectly and *at best* your whole application crashes. That's the happy path. It might be worse - it might continue working in a completely unknown state - great source for incredibly hard to track down bugs. Oh, and if a subsequent change needs *more* memory, you'd be out of luck in JS.

Comment: Thank you. I don't think there' s a memory leak because it is released. When you think how much memory is used in an application in which the user builds and edits data in indexedDB or even just navigates through previously added data, it is far more than would be used if memory was re-used.  For example, I made 500 large data packets, and used an interval to navigate through them every 500ms simulating user clicks, and just watched the RAM. At the end, after 45 sec or less, the memory was released, but was much higher during. It may have used less RAM if the all the data was held in RAM.

Comment: I'm not saying too much RAM is consumed in terms of becoming an issue in itself but that far more RAM is consumed than would ever be necessary if the memory could be re-used. I'm sure all methods have issues to workout. I'm not familiar with much of what you mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can allocated memory ever be programmatically re-used in JavaScript?

Yes, through [object pooling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pool_pattern). However, this is hardly ever reasonable, the native allocator/garbage collector will outperform this approach in 99% of the cases.

Comment: Thank you. This is interesting. These two links https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/static-mem-pools/ and https://blog.sklambert.com/javascript-object-pool/ provide some information also. It appears that all that is being done is altering an existing object's values or adding/removing properties. I don't think this would work in my specific indexedDB example because the database request will allocate data and that cannot be controlled.  I know that is not what you are answering here but just the question you quoted.

Comment: I upvoted this answer at first rather than accepting it as the answer, because the answer doesn't work for my example; but, that doesn't alter the fact that this is useful to know and is an answer to the more-limited question of whether or not memory can be re-used.  And it is exteremely doubtful that any further response will be received.